# sql How to achive this view table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to achieve this view from the following table.

(a)  I want to get two columns with group1 having distinct values where c3= yes and group2 where it has sum(c2) according to group1.

(b)  group 3 is the sum(c4) according to group1 and group4 is sum(c5) according to group 1 .How can it be done ?

```
c1   |   c2   | c3   | c4 | c5
--------------|---------------
A    |   2    |yes   | 1   | 2
B    |   1    |yes   | 2   | 1
A    |   2    |yes   | 1   | 2
B    |   1    |yes   | 2   | 1
C    |   2    |no    | 4   | 4
C    |   1    |no    | 4   | 4




result :


group1 | group2| group3| group4
--------------------------------
A      | 4     | 2     | 4
B      | 2     | 4     | 2
```

part a was resolved by this query

```
SELECT c1 as group1, SUM(c2) as group2 FROM table 
WHERE c3="yes"
GROUP BY c1
```

answered by Theo Babilon

but how to resolve part b and get a whole complete view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c1 as group1, SUM(c2) as group2, SUM(c4) as group3, SUM(c5) as group4
FROM table
WHERE c3 = "yes"
GROUP BY c1
```

Comment: Thanks working , but I have a problem now that I am posting in different question please look that too

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
SELECT c1 as group1, SUM(c2) as group2, SUM(c4) as group3, SUM(c5) as group4
FROM table
WHERE c2 = 'yes'
GROUP BY c1
```

Comment: you only missing c3 instead of c2 it should c3 , else working

Comment: @Muhammad muazzam:I answered 30 sec before that answer